# How to get android studio to refresh gradle deps?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I made a simple change in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.example:MyLib:1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.example:MyLib:SNAPSHOT'
```

There seems to be no gradle refresh button like with Intellij gradle projects though so I did a 'Rebuild all'.  Looking at my dependencies, android studio is still locked into the 1.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  they put it in a completely different location :( .  I found it in the top right clicking the left most icon in this image....

[image]